# Binding XML true or false to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have XML file like this

```
<Alarms>
    <Alarm>
        <Repeat>False</Repeat>
    </Alarm>
    <Alarm>
        <Repeat>True</Repeat>
    </Alarm>
</Alarms>
```

Trying to bind these boolean value in DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn using following code.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Alarms.xml");
foreach (var x in xdoc.Root.Elements("Alarm"))
{
    var repeat = x.Element("Repeat");
    bool repeat_v = repeat == null ? false : true;
    if (date != null)
        this.grid_SavedAlarms.Rows.Add(repeat_v);
}
```

It gives runtime exception without terminating the programme. and doesn't tick check boxes. Which one is the best method to cast boolean value to 'repeat_v'?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? what is the exception?

Comment: I think error is where you are adding boolean value into grid as a row, which can not cast bool to DataGridRow, you have to instantiate a DataGridRow with a boolean column and set that column to you boolean value, and add that row into grid.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a DataGridViewRow into your grid, and before that parse your Xml value into your boolean value

```
bool repeat_v = repeat == null ? false : bool.Parse(repeat.ToString());
if (date != null)
  {      
       DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
       row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell() {Value = repeat_v});
       this.grid_SavedAlarms.Rows.Add(row);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue my self. The problem was if you use repeat.Value, It gives us `True` or `False` not `true` or `false`.

That means c# boolean values are `true` or `false` not `True` or `False`. The correct code is

```
var repeat = x.Element("Repeat");
bool repeat_v = false;
if (repeat != null)
    repeat_v = repeat.Value == "True" ? true : false;
if (date != null)
    this.grid_SavedAlarms.Rows.Add(repeat_v);
```